# Jax-RS - sub resource objects gets written to output

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have a weird problem. I have a root resource and a sub resource (code is below).

When I call "/team/test" the call ends at "return subResource;" and the sub resource object is written as output to the response.

```
{
  "team": {
   "id": 1,
   "state": 1,
   "name": "test",
   "channels": []
  }
}
```

When I call "/team/test/name" i get a 404 response and in the server log this message is printed:

```
WARNUNG: No operation matching request path "/ts-webservice-dev/rest/team/test/name" is found, Relative Path: /test/name, HTTP Method: GET, ContentType: */*, Accept: */*,. Please enable FINE/TRACE log level for more details.
```

My applications server is tomee with apache cfx jax-rs implementation.
I have another application with very similar code on another machine and it's working correctly there. Unfortunatelly, I can neither test my current project  on the other machine nor test the other project on this machine.

Can you tell me, how I can solve this?

Root resource:

```
@Path("/team")
public class TeamResource extends BaseResource {

private TeamRepository teamRepository;

@GET
@Path("/{teamName}")
public TeamSubResource findTeam(@PathParam("teamName") String teamName) throws TeamInactiveException, TeamNotFoundException {
    Optional<TeamEntity> team = teamRepository.findByName(teamName);
    if (!team.isPresent()) {
        throw new TeamNotFoundException(teamName);
    } else if (team.get().getState() != 1) {
        throw new TeamInactiveException(team.get());
     } else {
        TeamSubResource subResource = CDI.current().select(TeamSubResource.class).get();
        subResource.setTeam(team.get());
        return subResource;
    }
}

@Inject
public void setTeamRepository(TeamRepository teamRepository) {
    this.teamRepository = teamRepository;
}
}
```

Sub resource:

```
public class TeamSubResource {

private TeamEntity team;

@GET
@Path("/")
public String test1() {
    return "test1";
}

@GET
@Path("/test")
public String test2() {
    return "test2";
}

@GET
@Path("/name")
public String name() {
    return team.getName();
}

public void setTeam(TeamEntity team) {
    this.team = team;
}

public TeamEntity getTeam() {
    return team;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I looked at it the next day with fresh eyes, I found the problem.

The @GET annotation at the subresource locator needed to be removed.